# How to stop/cancel the celery task by passing 'task_id' to a python function in django?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have celery task Id, I want to send it as query param to a django url endpoint and cancel/revoke the task using that task_id. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Celery AbortablerTask: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html

Or revoking:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#commands